Start Iterating Rows based on searched cell value
Is it possible to start looping/iterating over rows at a certain point in the Excel file based on a search for a cell value matching a search phrase in the worksheet?  In the below example, I need to look for the cell in column B having "End Customer Name" in it then start iterating over the cells below that until an empty cell exists to then stop the loop.
In my case the "End Customer Name" column starts at different rows for different xlsx files so I cannot use a specific row starting point.

